# Using Many to many with ef linq expression gave me "Unable to create a constant value of type (type)"

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table, Discounts which relates to CustomerGroups and Product.

Keys:

- Product has the key int ProductID.
- Discount has the key int DiscountID.
- CustomerGroup has the key int CustomerGroupID.

Relations:

- The relation between Discounts and CustomerGroups is one-to-many and
  nullable (a Discount has a nullable CustomerGroup).
- The relation between Discounts and Products is many-to-many and goes via a connection table Discount_Products. That table has a composite key consisting of the two ints DiscountID and ProductID. That connection table is automatically invisible in my model diagram and I get a relation where both ends are *.

I have a variable Discounts1 that I populate using EF:

```
IQueryable<Models.Discount> Discounts1 = _entities.Discounts;
```

What I want is to ask for all discount percentages for discounts that are not connected to a customer group and that are related to a certain product.

The linq expression I try to use is:

```
var candidates = (from discount in Discounts1
  where (discount.CustomerGroup == null)
  && discount.Products.Contains(product)
  select discount.Percentage).ToList();
```

What I get when I running this code is a NotSupportedException with a message

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'Models.Product'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Entity Framework can't translate the `Contains(product)` to SQL code. Your problem lies here:

```
discount.Products.Contains(product)
```

You should search the product by it's `ProductID`, which should be a primitive type.

This is a know issue which is documented here: [Referencing Non-Scalar Variables Not Supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#RefNonScalarClosures) :

> Referencing a non-scalar variables, such as an entity, in a query is
>   not supported. When such a query executes, a NotSupportedException
>   exception is thrown with a message that states "Unable to create a
>   constant value of type EntityType. Only primitive types ('such as
>   Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Comment: Now when I have got the clues, I would like to change the caption of the question

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` will break on non primitive types, although you can rewrite your query in a simpler way to avoid it (assuming `Product` has a primitive `ProductId` column)

```
from d in Discounts1
from p in d.Products
where d.CustomerGroup == null && p.ProductId == product.ProductId
select d.Percentage
```

Comment: I like the simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, Alex was the first to answer so I mark him as the solver.

```
var candidates = (from discount in Discounts1
  where (discount.CustomerGroup == null)
  && discount.Products.Any(p=>p.ProductID == product.ProductID)
  select discount.Percentage).ToList();
```